# Read restriction values using Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl, protege

I have an object restriction defined as follows

```
hasYear some integer[minLength 2, maxLength 4, >=1995, <=2012]
```

How can i read the individual values defined in the restriction using Jena.

Comment: I might suggest that if the reason you're trying to extract those values is because you want to enforce them, you look at using a reasoner to do that for you.

Comment: Ok. If that is possible, then how to implement it.  ie I read an integer value from a document and then i need to confirm that the value complies with the restrictions and therefore can be  considered as a 'YEAR'. I am new to OWL and Jena.

Comment: You don't really have to implement it, that's the point.  Just make sure your ontology is correct, and the reasoner will tell if you if something is inconsistent.  I suggest you read the OWL primer (http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-primer/), then check out a reasoner.  Jena comes with a few built in to get you started, but you can use other options like Pellet or Hermit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use different approaches. First of all you can traverse Jena `Model` by the following code:

```
model.read(...);
StmtIterator si = model.listStatements(
        model.getResource("required property uri"), RDFS.range, (RDFNode) null);
while (si.hasNext()) {
    Statement stmt = si.next();
    Resource range = stmt.getObject().asResource();
    // get restrictions collection
    Resource nextNode = range.getPropertyResourceValue(OWL2.withRestrictions);
    for (;;) {
        Resource restr = nextNode.getPropertyResourceValue(RDF.first);
        if (restr == null)
            break;

        StmtIterator pi = restr.listProperties();
        while (pi.hasNext()) {
            Statement restrStmt = pi.next();
            Property restrType = restrStmt.getPredicate();
            Literal value = restrStmt.getObject().asLiteral();
            // print type and value for each restriction
            System.out.println(restrType + " = " + value);
        }
        // go to the next element of collection
        nextNode = nextNode.getPropertyResourceValue(RDF.rest);
    }
}
```

If you use `OntModel` representation of RDF graph code can be simplified by using of

```
model.listRestrictions()
ontClass.asRestriction()
etc.
```

[Good example of such approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779927/get-restrictions-on-classes-in-jena/7805455) (thanks to Ian Dickinson)

Another way is to use SPARQL 1.1 query with the same meaning

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?datatype ?restr_type ?restr_value {
    ?prop rdfs:range ?range.
    ?range owl:onDatatype ?datatype;
        owl:withRestrictions ?restr_list.
    ?restr_list rdf:rest*/rdf:first ?restr.
    ?restr ?restr_type ?restr_value
}
```

Comment: "But there is a limitation that you can not retrieve restrictions which are specified by blank nodes (as Protege often does)." That's not correct - Jena will handle bNode restrictions perfectly well.

Comment: I've found no way to get *Restriction methods working on bnodes. It would be great if you could provide such example.

Comment: Lev: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779927/get-restrictions-on-classes-in-jena/7805455#7805455

Comment: Thanks for clarification. If you don't mind, I'll add this info to the answer.

Comment: Absolutely I don't mind - the main goal of StackOverflow is to collaboratively curate good answers to questions. So good job!